# Open file with hex numbers in Neo Hex Editor

Tags: hex, hexdump, hex-editors

I often require to interpret the file with hex numbers(may be called hex dump). Because I read the memory from the micro-controller and need to understand it, I thought, Neo-Hex Editor will help. But I found that Neo Hex Editor can open Intex-Hex Format, Motorola Hex format,Exe file, Image file etc.

But my file is series of hex numbers:

> '0x0', '0x0', '0x6', '0x0', '0x78', '0x56', '0x34', '0x12', '0x5', '0x0', '0x1'........

I want to open such file in Neo Hex Editor, where I can see the address location of particular number. Its character equivalent on the right etc.

Please let me know, if I need to arrange my hex file in proper format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Open the file in excel as a CSV file.
Transpose the row to a column
Remove all the apostrophes.
Remove all the 0x's.
Use this formula =char(A1)

It will look something like this (not all values are valid characters)

```
0   #VALUE!
0   #VALUE!
6   
0   #VALUE!
78  N
56  8
34  "
12  
5   
0   #VALUE!
```